# Clang (omp version) missing map and utility headers

Tags: c++11, clang, openmp, include-path, openmpi

I'm experiencing some sort of issue trying to compile a perfectly (windows+linux tested) mpi+openmp software I wrote my own.
I've managed to install and set to work the omp-adapted version of clang, and it works flawlessly in a simple omp "hello world" I've prepared.
As well I've installed open-mpi via homebrew, and the mpi "hello world" is working as well.
Now there come the issue.
Firstly, not so much confident in clang and openmp working together, I've created a version of my software without openmp calls. This version (MPI-only) of the code has been compiled with no issue.

Now comes my real dilemma.
I've reverted back the omp sections of my code, and tried to compile it with both MPI and openMP flags (mpic++ wrapper with ompclang forced in and -fopenmp flag added). The output of the compiler verbose mode is here below.

```
[...]
/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4/include/openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/mpicxx.h:39:10: 
fatal error: 'utility' file not found
#include <utility>
         ^
[...]
/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4/include/openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/mpicxx.h:39:10: 
fatal error: 'utility' file not found
#include <map>
         ^
[...]
```

After this output I tried to compile something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    std::cout<<"Hello World!!!!"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output keeps me saying the compiler can't find map, utility AND iostream as well.

It appears to me the problem is the compiler doesn't know where to find the standard c++ libraries.
Can anyone of you tell me how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Have fun,

gf

EDIT:

I've found a good suggestion from this site:

http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-users/2013-November/000293.html

That helped me to solve the issue.
I post the OMP+MPI hello world if anyone ever needs to test them together.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include "omp.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Print off a hello world message
    #pragma omp parallel 
        printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d,from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(),processor_name, world_rank, world_size); 

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Have fun

gf

Comment: Your last source, with iostream, map, utility - does it work with any clang version you have? Does it work with `clang`, `clang++` and with `mpic++` (ps: mpic++ should call clang++)? Which header they use (you can check used headers with `-H` option; compare header path from system's compiler). Clang usually tries to use system headers, checked in several predefined places (on Linux, don't know how it works on OSX), sometimes it can't find right place.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion.
Infact clang wasn't using the c++ libc++ system default path.
Adding the standard-clang path to the omp-clang header path (to the PATH) was enough to make it compile omp+MPI software.

Moreover I've discovered mpic++ supports the -fopenmp flag since I've installed the omp-clang version of the default compiler.
I've so managed to run a OMP+MPI helloworld, and everything is fine.
Thanks a lot to osgx for the suggestion!

Have fun

gf